# Function with Pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm trying to solve an exercise which asks for an array and counts the number of times that the number is equal to the average of the 2 numbers neighbours. I'm having a stupid error that I can't understand and it is giving me a headache.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 5

void neighbors(int *arr, int dim, int *equal){

int *t;
int *equal=0;
int i;

for(i=1;t[i]<=5;i++){
    if(((t[i-1]+t[i+1])/2)==t[i])
        equal++;
    else
        continue;
}
printf("Elements -> %d", &equal);
}

int main(){


int array[N]={1,2,3,9,10};
int aux;

int neighbors(*array,N,&aux);     // here it says "expected a ')' and "too many                          //                                           initializers"


system("pause");
}
```

Could you please give me a hint?
Thanks!

Comment: There are many more errors in this code ;) t[i+1] for i=5 will give you not the result you might expect. Redefining equal will also give you errors. And finally to increment the pointer equal but not the value. These are things you might want to rethink. I did not mention that your headers are not correct nor that you might want to use std::cout and not printf (with the wrong parameter). Have a look at http://codepad.org/MRh6ckbL it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more errors in this code:
`t[i+1] for i=5` will give you not the result you might expect. Redefining `equal` will also give you errors. And finally to increment the pointer `equal` but not the value. These are things you might want to rethink. I did not mention that your headers are not correct nor that you might want to use `std::cout` and not `printf` (btw: with the wrong parameter). Have a look at http://codepad.org/MRh6ckbL it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `int` at `int neighbors(*array,N,&aux);` and change it to `neighbors(array,N,&aux);` since you are passing a *pointer to an array* not a *value of the first member of that array*.

Also you redeclared equal at line 11.

And learn to read your compiler warnings/errors!

Comment: it says IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Answer (score 1):

Just this will do.

```
neighbors(array,N,&aux);
```

And note that `aux` is undefined.

Comment: What exactly are the `[]` doing here?